# Year with 13 months

Tags: time

Would it be possible to convince the world to have 13 months with 28 days rather than having 12 months with different numbers of days every month?

Disregarding historical reasons for our current situation at the moment, here are my ideas why this would be useful.

It would be much more reasonable in my opinion, since the week has 7 days, so one would always know at which day one would have appointments just by knowing the date.
Also, one would be able to plan into the future much easier, or look back to past events.

Even if one would argue with the moon phases, I think it wouldn't be a good argument, as one cycle take approximately 29.5 days, which doesn't fit with 30 and 31 days anyway.

I was wondering how it might be possible to implement this in our current society. Like how would one go about bringing public attention on this topic?

Comment: *"Would it be possible to convince the world to have a new standard"* https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: We have a hard enough time getting rid of daylight savings time; this would be a non-starter in current society. How to do it? Step 1: acquire dictatorial powers.

Comment: You'd have far more luck with 10months and alternating 36/37 days with the leap day as a dead day at new year.

Comment: I want a calendar that eliminates the concept of month altogether, has 52 numbered weeks per year, plus 1 day each year (2 on leap years) that are inserted as extra week-end days between Saturday and Sunday.  Every time I bring it up, I get laughed at.  (Comment posted on 11th Wednesday 2019.)

Comment: [you are not the only one to have this idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Fixed_Calendar)

Comment: Are you talking about building a **consistent fictional world** or about the real world? If it is about the real world, the question is out of scope.

Comment: Worth noting that OP [originally asked this on Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/39361/20220) and was redirected here.

Comment: This is in the VTC queue (OT:NAW). I disagree, the [help/on-topic] states, "World building includes geography, culture and creatures for the world, not to mention magic and planetary physics, in short, *everything from the physics underlying your reality to the entire universe you want to build.*" I believe this Q is on-topic. **However,** as currently asked, it's not asking a single, objective question but inviting a discussion. [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).  Therefore, I'm downvoting until improved.

Comment: The answer is obviously yes. It is neither logically contradictory, nor physically impossible; so it is *possible*. It is also very unlikely, unless your story finds a plausible (or entertaining, or tragic etc.) way to make it happen.

Comment: You do realise that people are still arguing about the pound vs kilogram, 200+ years after the latter was first standardised?

Comment: @nzaman, but they've gotta be different!  How else could we tell the difference between  2.2 pounds of grass (lawn clippings) and a key of grass (marijuana)?

Comment: @F1Krazy, sadly worldbuilding.SE is often mistaken as the dump of SE: whatever doesn't fit a community is addressed here, just because.

Comment: @l.dutch I now see that this topic easily raises discussion, and might possibly not be appropriate for SE. I am terribly sorry about this inconvenience. Would you, or anyone, have any suggestions for a place where this kind of question would be appropriate to ask?

Comment: @JBH: Does that mean if I stick to pounds I could sell "grass" without being bothered?

Comment: And what's your plan for the remaining 1 day? You should have a 29 days long month in your calendar. Also, your calendar soon deviates from the real Earth revolution if you don't implement a leap system in it. For it you have to have a leap year every 4 years (just like now)

Answer (score 4):

The biggest problem with this idea is that it completely fails to take into account the way people use the calendar.

12 is a wonderful number, it divides easily many ways. You can divide your year into halves, thirds, quarters, sixths, twelfths, without really thinking.

13 is prime and hence useless.

This is why the idea will never get any traction.

Comment: It should be pointed out that the Calendar was originally **10 months** (Hence *Septem*ber, the Seventh Month, *Octo*berm the Eighth Month, *Novem*ber, the Ninth Month, and *Decem*ber, the Tenth Month).  However, 2 Roman Emperors decided that, like the gods *Jan*us and *Mar*s, of the goddess *Jun*o , they too deserved a Month named after them.  And not a dreary month at the end of the year - a bright cheerful and sunny summer month.  So *Jul*ius Cæsar and Cæsar *August*us brought us up to 11 in 44BC and 12 in 8BC

Comment: @Chronocidal: *"2 Roman Emperors decided etc.":* This is fantastically wrong. Originally, named months stopped at June; then came numbered months, 5th (Quinctilis), 6th (Sextilis), 7th (September) and so on. Quinctilis was renamed July in honor of C. Julius Caesar, then Sextilis was renamed August in honor of Octavianus Augustus. Those were simple renamings, they did not add months. There is the shadow of a grain of truth in what you say; yes, loooong before emperors there were just 10 months, with the days between December and March not being allocated to a specific month, just "winter time".

Comment: @Chronocidal: The months September, October etc. are 7th, 8th etc. is because originally the year began in March. Fun factoid: until 1725, the English reckoned the years as beginning on 25 March.

Comment: I would not say that because 13 is prime it is useless. Kalam language, Kobon language both use a prime based number system. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numeral_systems

Comment: @Separatrix I would think that this is pretty much the main, if not the only reason why 12 would be favorable to other numbers. But as already stated, it was probably not introduced because people needed two extra months to divide the year nicely.

Comment: @PinkPanther, hard to say, for example there were 12 hours in a day for some time before those hours were the same length from one day to the next. Equally there were 12 months in the year long before quarterly returns were a thing.

Answer (score -1):

## It goes Viral

Trump, Trudeau, Warren Buffett, Snoop Dog, Weird Al, Bill Gates, and 20 other famous people (yes I know my list is western biased, this is not intentional) that anyone would at least know one of them is having a great party. All these people are arguing about what would be the best calendar out there.

At the end of it all, everyone is in agreement that to make calendars great again we need to change to [insert your system]. This video / audio recording / newspaper recount of what happened gets perceived by most people on earth. Towards the end you have a global shift towards your new system.

As long as the loud few care about your new system then eventually this should trickle down.